# How to deploy spring boot app on external tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

I have a spring boot app. It only has few api.

Its running fine on embedded tomcat server.

Now I need to deploy to my external tomcat server.

So I added **packaging as war** in pom file

I tried making a war **using export as war option** and put this war file inside my external **tomcat webapps** folder and tried running it. ***It failed with 404 status.***

**War file Name**

```
CghsMobileApp.war
```

My rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cghs")
public class HcoRestController {

    @Autowired
    private hcoService hcoSrvc;

    @GetMapping("/cghsCity")
    public List<CghsCity> getCghsCity() {
        return hcoSrvc.getCghsCity();
    }
}
```

**URL I tried to hit**

```
http://localhost:8080/CghsMobileApp/cghs/cghsCity
```

There is no html page inside my api project. Do I need to add one for war file to work.

I am lost here.
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: This could have many reasons. Can you provide us your pom.xml file? And give some more information about the project? Manly I would suggest that you are missing the /projectname on the path.

Comment: Ok sharing my pom file

Comment: I was confused, that can I deploy jar file using external tomcat. If so how?

Comment: try to reach the server by <serveraddress>/CghsMobileApp

Comment: I tried, by creating war file and adding it in tomcat webapps, it failed with 404 error

Comment: I looked inside the target folder and by default it generates jar file, so can I deploy that jar file directly, in some way

Answer (score 1):

Looked at the spring boot specification, found out that in class annotated with **@SpringBootApplication** have to extend **SpringBootServletInitializer**, for external server war deployment.

```
package gov.cghs.CghsMobileApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CghsMobileAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CghsMobileAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but unfortunately only this will not help when working with Spring Profile. If any of your classes are using `@Profile("profileName"),` it needs to be passed in.

With the fat jar it was easy with the command line parameter `--spring.profiles=<name>`

When deployed in an external Tomcat that external tomcat has to to be modified (that is catalina.properties requires a `-Dspring.profile=`)